# boost serialization for sockets

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'd like to use boost serialization to send a struct over the network using a socket. I looked at their tutorial (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) but it only shows saving and loading to a file.

I've modified my structs to include the serialize() function and tried using the same technique used in the tutorial for files with my socket, but no luck:

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

int sock = socket()...

boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(sock);
oa << mystruct;
```

> error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::archive::binary_oarchive::binary_oarchive(int&)’

So apparently it doesn't work this way with sockets. I googled and found this example that people were referencing:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/serialization/server.cpp

However, if you look at the comments in that example code:

```
// client. The connection::async_write() function will automatically
// serialize the data structure for us.
```

Well, I don't want to use asio for anything. I only want to serialize the data (using boost serialization) and send the data over a standard socket

Is the library not intended to be used this way? How can I use boost serialization with standard sockets (without asio)?

Comment: Uff, I think you have a huge concept mess. For what I understand, what you intend is to send a file over network, isn't it ?  So, you should read first the file and use its stream to send the bytes with the socket. Passing a socket descriptor to the constructor of binary_archive has no sense.

Comment: I have a struct in memory and I need to send the bytes over the wire. I can't just send &myStruct, sizeof(mystruct) because the struct contains pointers. I thought that it was normal to serialize in a case like this.

Answer (score 2):

The boost archive class constructor requires either a stream or a streambuf object. You can:

- Build/leverage a stream class that writes to a network socket, e.g. ASIO.
- Especially if the expected file size is small, you could serialize it to memory (using an ostringstream) and then writing the resulting data from the string to the socket using the normal functions.

Comment: If I wanted to try the second method, would I just create a std::ostringstream and then give that to the constructor? Then after serializing with boost just called read() to get the bytes?

Comment: I guess you'd have to get the string from the stream, and then write the char buffer behind it to the socket. Unless you have a special requirement no to use ASIO or the boost:.iostreams library mentioned in the other answer, I'd try to go down that route first, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`boost::iostreams::file_descriptor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file_descriptor.html). You can use it with `boost::iostreams::stream` or `boost::iostreams::stream_buf`.

Alternatively, consider [`boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/iostream.html) to wrap the whole raw sockets instead.

Comment: Good answer other than the fact that boost's documentation for tcp iostream makes no sense whatsoever. It doesn't show how to create one from the client side or server side or from a socket or endpoint or anything. Just some weird template that takes a bunch of parameters many of which are meaningless.